# Part of my hard drive just died... anything I can do to get my data back?

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery

One of the most important folders on my hard drive just died. It is no longer there at all. I got a few errors about files being corrupt before it disappeared. Anything I can do to get my data back?

Comment: Possibly, with a tool such as [NTFS Undelete](http://ntfsundelete.com/) -- but I would **strongly** recommend that, before you do anything else, you back up your entire hard disk. My experience has been that "random" corruption of this sort tends not to happen in isolation; the sooner you back up everything you can still read, the less likely it is that you'll lose anything else while attempting to recover the first batch.

Comment: What did the errors say? Did you run chkdsk?

Comment: Thanks for that tip. I got everything backed up, can I use NTFS on an external drive?

Comment: @Jenny: Yes you can.